# Searchkick send many queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a problem with Searchkick.
When I send query like this

```
Position.search(
  query.downcase,
  fields: [:name],
  include: [:brand],
  where: {},
  per_page: 40,
  page: 1,
  order: [:name]
)
```

Searchkick send request with many queries like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/positions_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"name.analyzed":{"query":"fly","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"name.analyzed":{"query":"fly","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}},{"match":{"name.analyzed":{"query":"fly","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}},{"match":{"name.analyzed":{"query":"fly","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}}]}},"size":40,"from":0,"sort":{"have_price":"desc"},"facets":{},"timeout":"11s","fields":[]}'
```

But when i change query to

```
Position.search(
  query.downcase,
  fields: [:name],
  include: [:brand],
  where: {},
  per_page: 40,
  page: 1,
  order: [:name],
  match: :word_start
)
```

Searchkick send this request with only two queries

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/positions_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"name.word_start":{"query":"fly","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_word_search"}}},{"match":{"name.word_start":{"query":"fly","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_word_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}}]}},"size":40,"from":0,"sort":{"have_price":"desc"},"facets":{},"timeout":"11s","fields":[]}'
```

> 'searchkick', '1.3.5'
>
> 'rails', '4.1.5'
>
> elasticsearch 1.7.4

How I can fix this and send only one queryes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need add `misspellings: false` to search method like this

```
Position.search(
  query.downcase,
  fields: [:name],
  include: [:brand],
  where: {},
  per_page: 40,
  page: 1,
  order: [:name],
  misspellings: false,
  match: :word_start
)
```